# (real analysis) Folland's proof of the Hahn Decomposition. (negative part proof)

Tags: real-analysis

In Folland's proof of Hahn Decomposition Theorem (p.86):

[image]

At first it says $\nu(A) >0$ for contradiction.

> Why can he say that "since $A$ cannot be positive, there exist $C\in A$ wuth $\nu(C) <0$ "?

I am quite confused about this logic (particularly for the existence of $C$)

---

The more complete part is as following:

[image]

Comment: I correct this by  providing more complete part of that proof to the part I ask.

Comment: Look back to the definition of positive/negative/null sets for signed measures on the same page.

Comment: I roughly get the idea. Since if $A$ should be negative, then the subset is also negative. However, here $\nu(A)>0$, and there is a negative subset. So does it imply the contradiction (which is exactly what the author want to say?)?